# In the early 1900s, would the name (Nettie/Nette) have been more likely to be spelled Nette or Nettie?

Tags: history

I am developing a family album.

In doing so, I have seen the name (Nettie/Nette) spelled both as Nette and as Nettie. I have not been able to locate relevant birth records.

Can someone tell me what the dominant spelling of this name was in the early 1900s.  In this instance, the specific year of birth was 1910.

I believe this is a question of etymology or usage.

Comment: Have you checked if it was a nickname? It may be that she was "Anette".

Comment: This Ngram Viewer chart strongly suggests that "Nettie" has been more common since at least the late 1850s: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nette%2C+Nettie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNette%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNettie%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Svoboda, to avoid confusion, you should verify the spelling used by Joyce in 'Eveline' and by the contemporary authors, anyway.

Comment: I should note that the difference in popularity is actually greater than the Ngram graph suggests, since most of the matches for "nette" have no connection to the woman's name, while most of the instances of "Nettie" do.

Comment: @Sven Y., yes, but Ngram can often be analysed with different procedures, sometimes leading to different conclusions, though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the historical spelling of a proper noun, not English as such.

Comment: It depends really on the community which is doing the writing. It's an abbreviation or pet name, which might represent Annette or Antoinette or anything of the sort in official records; and if the woman in question was the child of immigrants it's possible that both were in use among family and friends. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you might get more useful answers at [genealogy.se].

Comment: Nanette is another possibility as the given name of Nette/Nettie. A similar situation arises with "Bette," pronounced "Betty" in reference to Ms. Davis (1908-1989) and "Bet" in reference to Ms. Midler (1945- ), although this involves a difference of pronunciation rather than one of spelling.

Comment: My aunt, Nettie Lee Hicks, was born about 1905 in Louisville, KY.  "Nettie" was her given name.

Comment: The Nettie in our family was a Najda.

Comment: My guess would be that the spelling "Nette" would be used only if the family was one generation (or less) from immigration.

Answer (score 2):

As other commenters have noted, it depends on where the name is coming from. But a [search can be done](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=Nettie,Nette&year_start=1890&year_end=1940&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Nettie;,c0;.t1;,Nette;,c0) on Google Ngram, which compares the prevalence of a term in the vast database of Google Books. It shows that in 1910, Nettie was nearly 100 times more common.

Answer (score 0):

When I performed a census search for individuals born in the U.S. in 1910 with the first name of Nette on [Ancestry.com](http://ancestry.com), which can be performed for free without an account, I found 36,081 results. When I searched on Nettie, the results were 36,219. I.e., Nettie is only about 0.38% more likely to be a given name then Nette at that time.

[All 1910 United States Federal Census results for Nette](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?db=1910USCenIndex&gss=sfs28_ms_db&new=1&rank=1&msT=1&gsfn=Nette&gsfn_x=0&msbdy=1910&MSAV=1&uidh=000)

[All 1910 United States Federal Census results for Nettie](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?db=1910USCenIndex&gss=sfs28_ms_db&new=1&rank=1&msT=1&gsfn=Nettie&gsfn_x=0&msbdy=1910&MSAV=1&uidh=000)

A [Google Ngram Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Ngram_Viewer) search on the two names might show one name is more commonly found in books if there were more famous people named "Nettie" than there were named "Nette", though both might be fairly equally distributed as given names in the population. E.g., for 1910, the following individuals had "Nettie" as part of their name:

[Janet Gertrude "Nettie" Higgins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nettie_Palmer), the maiden name of "Nettie" Palmer (1885-1964), an Australian poet, essayist, and and Australia's leading literary critic of her day

[Nettie Maria Stevens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nettie_Maria_Stevens) (1861–1912), American geneticist

[Nancy "Nettie" Fowler McCormick](http://www.philanthropyroundtable.org/almanac/hall_of_fame/nettie_fowler_mccormick) (1835–1923), American philanthropist